# "Could not find or load main class" What does this mean?

Tags: java

I have never programmed with Java before. I tried making a `HelloWorld` program, following instructions from  a website. This is what my program looks like:

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class HelloWorld extends Applet
{
  public void paint (Graphics g)
  {
    g.drawString("Hello World!", 50, 25);
  }
}
```

Whenever I launch it, it says:

```
Could not find or load main class C:\Users\Leigh\Desktop\programs\Programming\HelloWorld.java`
```

Comment: I recommend starting with a Java tutorial, there's way too much to explain here.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could link to the website from where you found your 'learning instructions'.

Comment: Please use a different and more up to date source to learn Java; applets are already a bad idea, but this code on top of that points to a very OLD way to do applets.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add main method to your HelloWorld class, like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new HelloWorld();
}
```

Then your code will becomes as follows:

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class HelloWorld extends Applet {
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.drawString("Hello World!", 50, 25);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new HelloWorld();
    }
}
```

Comment: If it's an applet, you don't need/want a `main`, so that part's just wrong. "Run it as a Java Applet" is not useful instruction for a beginner.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Thanks for the information. Removed the content of "Run it as a Java Applet".

Comment: That wasn't the point. This doesn't answer the question. If you run what you have above via the `java` launcher (e.g., `java HelloWorld`), you'll see nothing, which doesn't help the OP.